# WSO2 MongoDB GridFS

Tags: mongodb, wso2, gridfs

I am new to WSO2.  I'm using wso2ei-6.5.0.  I'm trying to add MongoDB GridFS interaction to a data service I already have working with MongoDB.  I'm not finding any information in the WSO2 documentation.  Does anyone have any samples that can help me?

Working MongoDB data service code.  This will only insert documents into normal Mongo collections, not the GridFS collection where binary data gets stored in chunks.

```
<data name="MongoDB" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="">
<description/>
<config id="MongoAudit">
    <property name="mongoDB_servers">localhost</property>
    <property name="mongoDB_database">audit</property>
    <property name="mongoDB_write_concern">FSYNC_SAFE</property>
    <property name="mongoDB_read_preference">PRIMARY</property>
    <property name="mongoDB_maxWaitTime">60000</property>
</config>
<query id="mongoInsertAudit" useConfig="MongoAudit">
    <expression>mycollection.insert("{   correlation_id: #,    flowname: #,   payload: #}")</expression>
    <param name="correlation_id" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="flowname" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="payload" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <result element="UpdatedRowCount" rowName="Row" useColumnNumbers="true" outputType="XML">
        <element column="1" name="Value" exportType="SCALAR" xsdType="xs:integer"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="mongoInsertAuditOp">
    <call-query href="mongoInsertAudit">
        <with-param name="correlation_id" query-param="correlation_id"/>
        <with-param name="flowname" query-param="flowname"/>
        <with-param name="payload" query-param="payload"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried

Comment: Google searches did not return anything useful.  I certainly tried that and deeply searching this forum before posting.  As stated in my question, I have a working data service that interacts with MongoDB but only a normal collection.  I'll add that code to my original post if you think it will help.